# Difference between Yagna, Homam and Yagam?

Tags: yajna

What is the difference between yagna, yaaga and Homam?

Comment: Yaga and Yagya are just different English spellings of the Sanskrit word Yagna.  A Homa is small Yagna typically performed at home, as opposed to the elaborate Yagnas done in public.

Comment: but is there any difference between the procedures?

Comment: Sudarshana yagam was performed at Thirumala sometime back. Recently I heard some people performed Sudarshana homam at home. Will both give the same benefits ?

Comment: Yeah, Sudarshana Yagam and Sudarshana Homam are different names for the same ritual.

Comment: from this wiki link, the difference is blur between yagna and Homam and  rather they are interchangeable in present time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homa_(ritual)

Comment: Hi, I'm still not very clear on differences between Homa and Yagnam and Yagam. Kindly clarify.

Comment: Who is the Lord for Yagna as per vedam?

Comment: In Hindi they pronounce yagya in Marathi and Sanskrit it is yagnya

Comment: Someone earlier told me that a Yagyam (Yagya) is a detailed version of Homam. Homam are usually done in small time interval, usually around 1-3 hours. Yagyam are something that extends to about a year. Also the process is totally different, if am not wrong. I'm extremely curious to know the difference and shall update if I come to know in future :)

Answer (score 4):

Sri Kandadai Ramanujacharya while answering **What is Ishti?** (e.g., putra-kama-**ishti**) in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BB81l9LG2M&feature=youtu.be&t=775) episode of Telugu Bhakthi TV program Dharma Sandehalu says the following:

> That which fulfills your desire is called Ishti. In a broader sense ishti is a yajna but when the yajna is done for just a few hours in a single day to fulfill one's minor desires, it is called ishti. Ishti is done to please the God that can fulfill those particular desires.
>
> The different yajna's depending on the actual time you spend on them are classified as:
>
> 1. **Ishti** (1 or 2 hours, e.g., Lakshmi-Narayana Ishti, Sudarshana Ishti, Narasimha Ishti, Hayagriva Ishti (for better studies), Vishwaksena Ishti (to remove obstacles) and Vaibhava Ishti (for wealth)
> 2. **Homam** (1 day)
> 3. **Yajna** (3, 5, 11 days or 3 months)
> 4. **Maha-yaagam** (1 or 2 months)
> 5. **Advaram** (6 months or 1 year)
> 6. **Satram** (50, 100, 500 years or 1000 years)

Comment: Does any kings or devotees performed Maha-yaagam, Advaram and Satram?

Comment: `Maha-yaagam` are performed in various parts of India now-a-days also.